# How can I create a chromium-like background app?

Tags: application-development, programming, development

I want to create an application that (like `chromium`) creates an icon on the top menu bar and after you close the application, the icon is still there and the application continues running in the background.

[image: chromium example]

Comment: What are you using to make the app?  If it's a Gtk app, you just override the destroy handler and capture the signal.  I have an example of that laying around somewhere.

Comment: @hbdgaf Preferably I would be using python with tkinter, but whatever works. I'm new to desktop apps. Please give me as much info as possible, and the examples. Thank you.

Comment: ...And what would be the background process for the application?

Comment: @JacobVlijm basically update every few minutes to send me notifications etc. Why does that matter though?